# Mouse-over objects not possible in HTML export of Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need help with mouse over content of the HTML export from Enterprise Architect. I would like the HTML output from Enterprise Architect to also contain the 'Notes' of the element when I mouse over them. Currently this is not possible with the standard HTML export from Enterprise Architect. 
Actually there is no way to see the contents and tags of the element if it has a composite child structure except for you have to find it in the side window like project browser and then click the individual object from there.
Please let me know if there are some ways I can achieve these.

Cheers!
Neha

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the mouseover option is possible since the actual clickable areas are not related to the elements, they just redirect to the elements page.

But when clicking on an element on the HTML model, it should show you its details :notes, attributes, diagram, etc...(If it shows you the diagram, rest of the content should be below it)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the mouse over.

Regarding the contents of the diagram, I'll try to explain with a scenario.
I have Diagram A with 3 composite activities. All the three composite activities have descriptions and other linked elements from other diagrams. Now when I'm on the html output with Diagram A on the screen, I cannot see the description and linked diagrams of any Activities. If I want to see the details I'll have to navigate and find this activity on the left pane and click. Is there a better way to do it ot include these information in the diagram. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: is the diagram an actual child of the element? If you double-click the lement inside of ea, does it open the elements diagram?

Comment: @NehaRamesh thinking about it, which browser are you using to consult the HTML model?

Comment: Yes it is the actual child. when I click on the element then the diagram opens. Also in the Project browser it is placed under the right Business Process. I'm using EA version 12. I check ed internet explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Basically I get the Created, Modified, Project: (Author, Version), Advanced: (ID) but no details about the child elements